# Perdida de foco en un input

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

Hola quisiera saber porque cuando quiero buscar alguna palabra del datatable este no se ejecuta al momento que le doy enter si no con la perdida de foco osea un click fuera del input. Esto solo sucede con internet explorer.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es un datatable? ¿Puedes concretar más la pregunta? ¿Sólo usaste IE, eres funcionario/a?

Comment: ¿El datatable es un plugin? si es ¿cual es? si es custom algo de código ayudaría mucho.

Comment: Un datatable es una tabla de datos dinámica y es un plugin de JQuery.